# Correct Method To Store Variables On Firebase For Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I integrated firebase into my android app successfully. Since then I have read every single tutorial, doc, tips, info, code examples, and of course, scoured stack overflow, with no way to accomplish my goal here.

I have two variables in my slot machine game, mTokens and mSpins. Right now they are declared in my mainactivity, so they obviously reset every time you open the app. I was able to store them under a userid in firebase. However, I have no Idea how to increase or decrease them, when a user uses spins, or wins tokens, rather than just setting the variable again. I also need to display both values in textviews, but I've tried countless changes in code, and it usually crashes the app. Either it returns null, or not a string. And the one time it almost worked, it didn't update on create, but once I manually called it on a button press.

So to organize:

How to manipulate the variables based on gameplay(add or subtract) in regards to storing with firebase.

And

How to show stored values as live textviews on toolbar throughout app.

And to reiterate, yes. I've read every example I could find, rather it applied or not. I work Google like a boss, so it really gets me that I had to result to asking. Was going to email firebase,  they suggest asking here to help others in the future.

This is how my code looks at the moment, but I've edited and changed it a considerable amount of times. So I have have been closer to a solution before, and had no idea.

I'm also leaving the firebase url, so the structure van be seen.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://luckycashslots.firebaseio.com/data/users/" + MainActivity.uID + "/");
Firebase tokRef = ref.child("tokens");

//tokRef.setValue(mAuthData.getProvider());

//Tokens token = new Tokens(100);

//ref.setValue(token);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.child("tokens").getValue() != null) {
            name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("tokens").getValue().toString();
            tokens.setText(name);
            //tokens.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            // String woot = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            // tokens.setText(woot);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "couldnt update token text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of describing the code, show a minimal, complete example of what you're asking about. Most developers find it easier to read code than text and you're much more likely to get a helpful answer if you include code that we can scan first. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: *Code added. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

To change an existing value in Firebase, you use a transaction.

From the [Firebase documentation on transactions in Android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions):

```
Firebase upvotesRef = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/android/saving-data/fireblog/posts/-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY/upvotes");
upvotesRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {
        if(currentData.getValue() == null) {
            currentData.setValue(1);
        } else {
            currentData.setValue((Long) currentData.getValue() + 1);
        }
        return Transaction.success(currentData); //we can also abort by calling Transaction.abort()
    }
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
        //This method will be called once with the results of the transaction.
    }
});
```

Please read the entire docs, because it covers many topics and problems you may run into.